# PHP to sort course list by days of week from api

Tags: php

I'm using my school's api for the cs departments course schedule. It provides me a json file that I'm outputting on my webpage separated by each semester. Currently I'm able to have the output of all the courses in each semester sorted by the course ID. However, I'm trying to sort each semester by the day that the class is offered. Monday and Monday/Wednesday classes would be listed first, then Tuesday and Tuesday/Thursday and so on.

In my printListings function I'm able to print the entire course schedule out. And I'm able to add the line:

```
// if first character of days is an "M" 
if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'M')) continue;
```

which causes only monday and monday/wednesday courses to appear. However if I try adding a copy of the same line and just change the "M" to a "T" it causes no courses to appear. Such as:

```
if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'M')) continue;
if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'T')) continue;
```

I know this is due to both statements together are skipping all courses, since no coursecan start with both "M" and "T". I need to use multiple loops for setting this up but am unsure with how to properly set it up.

printListing function:

```
function printListing($apiCall) {

    $json = curl_get_contents($apiCall);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    if (!($obj->courses == null)) {

        echo "<table border='3' width='100%'>";

        foreach ($obj->courses as $course) {

            // if first character of days is an "M" 
            if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'M')) continue;

            //if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'T')) continue;
            //if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'W')) continue;
            //if(strcmp(substr($course->meetingTimes[0]->days, 0, 1), 'R')) continue;

            $building = strtoupper(trim($_GET['building']));
            $buildingMatch = false;
            $thisBuilding0 = trim($course->meetingTimes[0]->building);
            $thisBuilding1 = trim($course->meetingTimes[1]->building);
            if ($building && ($thisBuilding0 == $building || $thisBuilding1 == $building))
                $buildingMatch = true;
            if (!($building))
                $buildingMatch = true;
            if (!$buildingMatch)
                continue;

            $room = strtoupper(trim($_GET['room']));
            $roomMatch = false;
            $thisroom0 = trim($course->meetingTimes[0]->room);
            $thisroom1 = trim($course->meetingTimes[1]->room);
            if ($room && ($thisroom0 == $room || $thisroom1 == $room))
                $roomMatch = true;
            if (!($room))
                $roomMatch = true;
            if (!$roomMatch)
                continue;

            // different <tr bgcolor=...> for each professor
            switch ($course->meetingTimes[0]->instructor) {
                case "proff1":            // 1
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='#B19CD9'>";  // pastel purple
                    break;
                case "proff2":             // 2
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='lightblue'>";  // light blue
                    break;
                case "proff3":           // 3 
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='pink'>";  // pink
                    break;
                case "proff4":           // 4
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='yellow'>";   // yellow
                    break;
                case "proff5":           // 5
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='#77DD77'>";  // pastel green (light green)
                    break;
                case "proff6":           // 6
                    $printline = "<tr bgcolor='#FFB347'>";  // pastel orange
                    break;
                default:
                    $printline = "<tr>"; // no background color
            }

            $printline .= "<td width='13%'>" . $course->prefix . " " . $course->courseNumber . "*" . $course->section . "</td>";
            $printline .= "<td width='40%'>" . $course->title . " (" . $course->lineNumber . ")" . "</td>";
            $printline .= "<td width='12%'>Av:" . $course->seatsAvailable . " (" . $course->capacity . ")" . "</td>";

            // print day and time column
            if ($course->meetingTimes[0]->days) {
                $printline .= "<td width='15%'>" . $course->meetingTimes[0]->days . " " . $course->meetingTimes[0]->startTime;
                // $printline .= . "<br /> " . $course->meetingTimes[1]->days . " " . $course->meetingTimes[1]->startTime ;
                $printline .= "</td>";
            } else {
                $printline .= "<td width='15%'>";
                $printline .= $course->meetingTimes[1]->days . " " . $course->meetingTimes[1]->startTime . "</td> ";
            }

            // print building and room column
            $printline .= "<td width='10%'>";
            if (substr($course->section, -2, 1) == "9")
                $printline .= "(Online)";
            else
            if (substr($course->section, -2, 1) == "7")
                $printline .= $course->meetingTimes[1]->building . " " . $course->meetingTimes[1]->room;
            else
                $printline .= $course->meetingTimes[0]->building . " " . $course->meetingTimes[0]->room;
            $printline .= "</td>";

            // print instructor column
            $printline .= "<td width='10%'>" . $course->meetingTimes[0]->instructor . "</td>";
            $printline .= "</tr>";
            echo $printline;
        } // end foreach

        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br/>";
    } // end if (!($obj->courses == null))
    else {
        echo "No courses fit search criteria";
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what the issue is here but you should write better code. You are only using one function, which I think can be split into two other functions. Try writing it better and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I have multiple functions for the webpage, this is the only function I'm having issues with though. It's the only one that prints all the courses under each semester.

Comment: I am suggesting that you break this function down further and make it clear like html table output, sorting the JSON function and a file/DB writing function.

Comment: can you post the full json for a M/W course and a T/R course?